# How to prove the inequality over expectation $E |u^H X v|^{2t}\le E |u^H J v|^{2t}$?

Tags: inequality, random-variables, expected-value

Assume that $X \in R^{M\times N}$ has positive entries and $\| X \|_F^2=MN$. The random vectors $ u \in C^{M\times 1}$ and $ v \in C^{N\times 1}$ have entries given by
\begin{align}
u_m = e^{j\theta_m}, v_n  =e^{j\phi_n},
\end{align}
where $\theta_m$ and $\phi_n$ are i.i.d. uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$. I want to prove the following

\begin{align}
E |u^H X v|^{2k}\le E |u^H J v|^{2k},
\end{align}
where $J \in R^{M\times N}$ is all one matrix and $k\ge 0$ is integer.

---

I have done some numerical simulations, which implies the inequality holds. But how can we prove it? Any idea is appreciated!